# How to get a duplicate page in InDesign to sit below its original?

Tags: adobe-indesign

When duplicating a page in InDesign in the pages panel (either by right clicking and duplicate, or by dragging the page down to the new page icon) is it possible to get the new duplicate page to sit below its original rather than going to the bottom of the page stack?

I'm using InDesign CC subscription, but I guess it will be the same for most versions as it's a pretty core/fundamental feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just hold ALT and drag the pages where you want them. You'll see a thin vertical line where your pages will be placed.

Comment: Is this the only way? I often have presentations where I might want to 'inject' a duplicate for a number of reasons, and if you have 100 slides, going to get the duplicate from the bottom is very inconvenient and timeconsuming.

Comment: You can in the pages panel, while selecting one or multiple pages, right click and choose 'Move pages'. Use the Move pages dialogue to choose exactly where you want to move them and to which document.

Comment: that may well be, but it still requires the action of taking note of the page number, going down, finding the page you want, opening the menu, etc etc. If you do this a lot, it quickly gets tedious, in my humble opinion.